# How to find out which Android APP is using content provider to monitor system data ?

Tags: android, detect, contentobserver

all,

I know I can monitor the change of android Content with ContentObserver to monitor

Android System data, but is it possible to have an list of APPs which is monitoring system via

the ContentObserver ?

For instance, I try to find a solution to detect android APP runs the following code:

```
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS), true, 
contentObserver);
```

Any idea ? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, this is not possible, except by modifications to the operating system itself.